# Default Permitted Users to "Admin approved" in connected Apps with installed Packages

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, canvas

I've built a Canvas App using Signed Requests and therefore I need the Permitted Users option set to "Admin approved" (otherwise Salesforce doesn't send any Signed Request). I've set this option to "Admin approved" in my App and everything works fine when I use the Canvas App Previewer.

However, when I package the App and install it in another developer environment, the option Permitted Users is set to "All Users" :( Therefore I have to change the value of this option to be able to receive the Signed Request.

Is there any way to make things simpler for the admin that will install my App such as setting the default value of the Permitted Users value to "Admin approved" ?

Thanks in advance for all your answers!

Cheers

Quentin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no way to specify this in your package at this time. You will need to include that in your documentation, and possibly also program your app to notify users that they need to contact an admin when this situation is detected.

Comment: Is there documentation that states this is normal behaviour? I have looked and haven't found anything. But that doesn't mean it isn't documented.

Comment: @JoshPeak https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/quick_start_config_who_can_access_installed_canvas_app.htm

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to do this via a post-install script and the metadata API:

[How can I programmatically set a connected app to have permitted users be "Admin approved users are pre-authorized"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/276289/how-can-i-programmatically-set-a-connected-app-to-have-permitted-users-be-admin)

Comment: Well, that is not a post-install script and this won't work for packaged connected app in subscriber org