# How can I programmatically set a connected app to have permitted users be "Admin approved users are pre-authorized"?

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

Background: I am making a managed package and have a connected app that needs to have permitted users set to "Admin approved users are pre-authorized" for it to work correctly:

[image]

It is a terrible experience for admins installing my app to make them change this value (and this is typically the step that they get wrong).
Does anyone know of a way to change this value programmatically...like in a post-install script? It would make it much better for the users.

---

What I have tried so far:

I tried changing the xml via instructions on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm by adding `<isAdminApproved>true</isAdminApproved>` to the `<oauthConfig>` part of the .xml for my connected app, but the behavior of scratch orgs created that way was unchanged.

Comment: Duplicate of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271632/metadata-api-apex-fails-to-create-fields-in-connected-app

Comment: Related [Control Managed Package Connected App Permission Set from managed code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/77130/102)

Comment: [Summer '20 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm) is giving extra access to the Metadata API, like to `oauthConfig` and `oauthPolicy`. Not sure if it's editable in production but worth exploring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you to identigral and daniel-ballinger for your helpful comments! With your help, I was able to figure it out.

Please see the post-install script snippet below (which leverages a tweaked version of apex-mdapi: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/pull/242/commits) on how to switch it to "Admin Users are pre-authorized" and set some profiles.

```
    //gets the actual MetadataPort object and pulls the session id
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    //grabs the pre-existing connected app that I already created as part of my managed package
    MetadataService.ConnectedApp connectedApp = (MetadataService.ConnectedApp)service.readMetadata('ConnectedApp', new String[] {'My_Connected_App'}).getRecords()[0];

    //adds in the appropriate profileNames and sets isAdminApproved to be true
    connectedApp.profileName = new List<String>();
    connectedApp.profileName.add('System Administrator');
    connectedApp.profileName.add('Standard User');
    connectedApp.oauthConfig.isAdminApproved = true;

    //saves the updates
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results = service.updateMetadata(new MetadataService.Metadata[] {connectedApp});
```

Comment: It turns out this doesn't work in prod. Please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/286527/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-connectedapp-settings-in-production for further developments on this topic.

Comment: by prod, do you mean this doesn't work in the subscriber org, which might be sandbox as well, correct?